When translating controls into German, do I assume a German keyboard?
I am translating a video game into German, and I am wondering about the keys listed for the controls in the settings. On an American keyboard we have QWE, AD, and ZXC forming a square that the player can easily use with their left hand, so those are default controls. But on a German keyboard the Z and the Y have switched places, so do I need to put a Y in place of the Z for the translation? Can I assume that German-speaking people are not using the American keyboard setup?

Can you share any information about the engine or libraries the game in question uses? Different tech stacks will often have different ways of handling localization of text/input, so we can give you more specific answers if we have more details about your situation.

@odduse_of_language: It might help to clarify if you are "just" the translator or if you are also the/a developer and therefore have access and understanding of the code.

No, I am just a volunteer translator, so I don't know much about the code itself.

If it's just a "positional thing", you should have a keyboard illustration with the "zones" mapped out; then refer to a (key combination) zone by "zone #" (it's then multi-lingual)

Some advice for the developers you are working with:
Game SDKs usually have a method to access keys in a "keyboard layout agnostic" way. For example, the Unity documentation writes:

The location of individual keys is agnostic to keyboard layout. This means that, for example, the A key is always the key to the right of the Caps Lock key, regardless of where the currently active keyboard layout places the key that generates an a character, or whether or not the layout doesn't have a key assigned to that character.

If you don't use a game SDK or the one you use does not support this feature, your development system will still allow you to query the current keyboard layout, which you can use to do your initial setup: If the user currently uses a German keyboard layout, just map the Y and Z keys (and others, if relevant) differently.

So, to directly answer your question:

Can I assume that German-speaking people are not using the American keyboard setup?

There is no need to assume anything. The game can just ask the operating system to tell it which keyboard the user is using at run-time.
If you are not a developer but just providing text content or translations, don't hard-code the key letters (neither in the original English version nor in the translated versions). There should be placeholders, and the developers should make sure that those placeholders are filled according to the current keyboard mapping at run-time. E.g. the text resource should be "Press {MoveLeftKey} to move to the left" rather than "Press A to move to the left".

Note that this answer was written for a non-technical StackExchange site (german.stackexchange.com) before the question was migrated, hence the hyperlink explaining what an SDK is, etc. Feedback from the gamedev community to make the post more in line with the expectations here is always welcome.

Thanks for your consideration, @Heinzi, and welcome to our site! I think this is a great answer already, providing sound general advice to orient an unfamiliar reader on the topic and establish good baseline expectations. If the asker shares more details about their tech stack, users can address the more specific technical points in another answer.

Really, don’t assume anything. There are Germans living in the USA using a French keyboard so you check and see they use a French keyboard. You could check their location, but the user can tell the OS what location to assume. So an American on holiday of business in Germany has their computer working as always. But if a user looks for a “bakery near me” you take their actual location because telling a hungry American in Germany about a bakery in manhattan isnt helpful.

Great answer.  The term is keycode and is locale unaware. Neither the printing on the keycap, nor OS locale/keyboard setting, changes the keycode value.  The SDL project provides common mappings if anyone is interested on this topic.

You don't assume a German keyboard. You ask the operating system what keys there are on the keyboard and where they are. And you check what other apps are doing.
Games will often use four keys in some arrow pattern to control something, say jkim for "left, right, up, down" on a British keyboard. So you ask the operating system to check which keys are at those positions and use those four keys. Blindly using jkim would make it hard to play your game if they are not in an arrow pattern. And using the keys for a German keyboard when a German player uses a US or French or British keyboard would be equally bad.
Or say you want to use the key above a digit. On my keyboard shift-8 equals "*". So then you decide: Did you really want shift-8 or "*" to control some functionality? You'd use shift-8 for "very similar to 8, but a bit different". So you decide, and then you figure out how to detect that the user pressed shift-8, and not "*", on their keyboard, which might be any language.
And as an exception, it seems to be standard to use z/x/c/v for undo/cut/copy/paste everywhere, even on German keyboards where z is on a different row. This makes your situation more interesting: If you want to”8 characters in a square”, then the developers should use the operating system which keys are in these positions on your users keyboard. For example the bottom left key is Y on a German keyboard, and French keyboards use AZERT instead of QWERT. But if you use undo/cut/copy/paste then check other applications but many use zxcv. So you can’t have just one translation. Now let’s get extreme: I could have two keyboards connected in different languages and need different keys depending on where the user types.

+1 , please note that your asterisks in "shift-8 equals "*" where eaten by the formatter.

Thanks. Fixed it.

Usually yes. Translation is more than translation of the words. In software development this process has actually its own word: 'localization' to include the adoption to the target audience beyond just the words
In the context of translating controls of a programme or game, it's not necessarily the only work of the translator themselves to ensure correct functioning though: it is work which has to be supported by the programmers, too. There are different methods to access keys from a program's perspective (by value or by position on the keyboard) and you have to make sure that you describe what is actually being used as inputs - thus test that your translation matches the actual behaviour and talk to the programmers if the layout of the used keys does not match the intended ones. Thus key mapping should usually be language dependant.
Depending on context you also may want to translate units used in text, e.g. for distances, volumes etc. A German audience usually will not have a good idea of the numbers if a person's height is referenced in feet and inch and their weight in stones or pounds. The efficiency of a car is expressed in miles to a galon in English but in litres per 100km in German etc.
But there may be contexts where translating units to the usual unit in the target language is also detrimental, e.g. when it matters that the setting is explicitly in the US. Use your translator's judgement.

Gas efficiency: In the USA/UK more is better. In Germany, smaller is better.

Short answer: You cannot just translate it, but to be correct more likely: do translate it.
You are right, the german keyboard layout differs in the Y/Z keys.
You can assume players will use their own language specific layout first, not the english layout.
But you need to know what the game code is doing to translate that button the correct way.
There are two options:

Either the code adheres to the locale of the operating system, then the Z input would automatically be send when pressing a german Y and you would have to translate it to reflect the correct position in the lower left corner of the keyboard for that functionality. This case is the more likely one in modern games.

The other effect will be that the game code "hardcoded" that a "z" is the input (the character or ASCII code of it). In this case also a german player has to input a "z", which is the key in the center of the upper row on his keyboard.


And this is a problem since... forever.
In the end, it doesn't really matter (for your translation; the usability will be largely affected by how the game code works).
Either the game provides a function to remap those keys or the defaults are changed during install or the player presses that key, realizes it doesn't work, tries Z instead and succeeds, curses the developer (and not anybody else involved) for approximately 3.34325 seconds whenever the Z key needs to be pressed, but continues playing his game anyway (or changes the locale or uses software-remapping tools or quits, cursing for longer).

oh, it totally matters. Hardcoding an ascii value may make a programme or game much less or even not at all accessible, if the character is on a different code page in the high ascii region (like the German ä,ö,ü). Or ask Germans to input []{} - they are accessible, but far from as nicely as on a US layout keyboard.

that is the most obvious example as it is a letter. But let the programme access the keys immediately left of the return key. Hillarity ensues.

There are keyboards with completely different layouts. If you plug a new keyboard into a Mac, you will be asked to press (can't remember exactly) the key immediately left of the return key, or immediately right of the shift key, and then the OS figures out which physical keyboard you have.

Yes, I get it. But the question (my answer at least) is more focused on the problem of translation. Not on the problem of usability. I added a sentence to make that more clear.
